# How to install AIR 4.0 SDK into Flash Pro CC

Tags: flash, air, flash-cc

I just downloaded the v4.0 of AIR from http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html?promoid=DJGYD and I'm trying to figure out how to integrate this into Flash Pro CC.

I tried coping the contents of the zip to C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Flash CC\AIR4.0 figuring that maybe it was smart enough to scan for new SDKs but no such luck.

What do I have to do to get Flash Pro to become aware of it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out this is a lot easier than I thought.

Click the Help menu item. Click the Manage AIR SDK item.
When the screen opens, click the + sign and navigate to the folder where you extracted the SDK to.

That's it! Now you should be able to pick this SDK from the list of options in Flash.

Here's the link I used. The bottom section is about the newer version of Flash.
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/enable-the-latest-air-sdk-in-flash-professional-cs55--active-11488